# Django templates - Check if user already has created an object for another object

Tags: django

I have 2 models called `Valuation` and `Assessment`.  A valuation has many assessments (foreignkey relationship).  Users can only create 1 assessment for each valuation.

This seems to be very simple but I can't wrap my head around it.  I need to check if any of a valuation's existing assessments belongs to the request.user, how do I do that?

**this doesn't work because `assessment_set.all` is a list. (`assessments` in this case is a list of assessments for the currently displayed valuation)**

```
{% if request.user.assessment_set.all not in assessments %}
    # Display "make an assessment" form
{% endif %}
```

So I think I'd need to loop over `request.user.assessment_set.all` and see if each of the user's assessments is in the `assessments` list, but I feel like that is very inefficient and there must be a better way.  Advice?

Comment: post your models so that its easy to understand

Comment: You shouldn't really be performing this kind of logic in the template - it would be better to do it in the view code (e.g., annotate each `assessment` to say whether the user has already completed it), and then your template logic will be straightforward.

Comment: you want to check if the user have created a object already?

Comment: I did the processing in the views and I was able to display it properly on the page.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description I assume you have the following model architecture(i have used related_name for the reverse relationships),

```
class Valuation(models.Model):
    # fields

class Assessment(models.Model):
    #fields
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='assessments')
    valuation = models.ForeignKey(Valuation, related_name='assessments')
```

So if you want to limit the logged in user to create only 1 assessment for each valuation, then you present only those valuations that are not assessed.

views.py

```
unassessed_valuations = Valuation.objects.exclude(assessments__user=request.user)
```

template

```
{% for valuation in unassessed_valuations %}
valuation assessment form
{% endfor %}
```